Sewage not flowing through/blockage but very irregularly
I live in an old 1930 apartment in The Hague NL; on the ground floor. An apartment like this.
Our drainage in the kitchen is very weird and inconsistent. It seems to irregularly get blocked or slow down but it seems to have no effect on what we do.
Normally the water flows away, but sometimes it gets stagnant and the sewage seems to get stuck. putting unblocker in it seems to help for a while, but it randomly gets blocked a few months later again. Sometimes it gets slowly blocked and sometimes it gets really blocked really quickly out of nowhere.
Last week I unblocked it again (with chemicals) and it was running fine again, but not a week later, it seems to get blocked sometimes for a short period of time and then flow again. I only have this problem in the kitchen but not in the bathroom or toilet. Also when this happens again the drainage starts bubbling and I get a terrible smell. Now it seems to be almost completely blocked again.
I feel like it could only be my upstairs neighbours but I have no idea how the drainage is connected. I went to to government to get the maps of the house but it was from 1930 and it had no details on the drainage or sewage system. (any other things im thinking is Main sewage is full, but then the toilet wouldn't drain either and the government would probably tell us. Or rodents in our sewage system sometimes temporarily blocking it but thats probably just wild imagination?)
More details:

Sewage enters the house from the front
Bathroom is halfway the house, then the toilet and kitchen is in the back
Kitchen also has a dishwasher.
I now try to use a lot of hot water but still it gets clogged.
I'm not sure what my neighbours are doing. I have a good connection with the homeowners but one apartment is rented out to students and switches tenants quite often.

Some questions I have:

How would I go about investigating and finding the cause of this?
How would I get an idea on how the drainage is connected?
Any other advice you could give me?


Kitchen sinks tend to have some stuff poured down the drain that really should be.  Fats/food particles/soap tend to bind to pipes, plus sink drain pipes are about 5cm diameter instead of the bigger pipes of the toilet/main line.  Snaking the pipe might help some.

I certainly hope the sewage leaves the house from the front, rather than entering ;^)

@crip Yea we make sure not to pour these things down the drain
